# int numeral -> pointer conversion rules

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types

Consider the following code.

```
void f(double p) {}
void f(double* p) {}

int main()
{ f(1-1); return 0; }
```

MSVC 2017 doesn't compile that.  It figures there is an ambiguous overloaded call, as `1-1` is the same as `0` and therefore can be converted into `double*`.  Other tricks, like `0x0`, `0L`, or `static_cast<int>(0)`, do not work either.  Even declaring a `const int Zero = 0` and calling `f(Zero)` produces the same error.  It only works properly if `Zero` is not `const`.

It looks like the same issue applies to GCC 5 and below, but not GCC 6.  I am curious if this is a part of C++ standard, a known MSVC bug, or a setting in the compiler.  A cursory Google did not yield results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MSVC considers `1-1` to be a null pointer constant. This was correct by the standard for C++03, where all integral constant expressions with value `0` were null pointer constants, but it was changed so that only zero integer literals are null pointer constants for C++11 with [CWG issue 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903). This is a breaking change, as you can see in your example and as is also documented in the standard, see [[diff.cpp03.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/diff.cpp03.conv) of the C++14 standard (draft N4140).

MSVC applies this change only in conformance mode. So your code will compile with the `/permissive-` flag, but I think the change was implemented only in MSVC 2019, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements?view=vs-2019#implicit-conversion-of-integral-constant-expressions-to-null-pointer).

In the case of GCC, GCC 5 defaults to C++98 mode, while GCC 6 and later default to C++14 mode, which is why the change in behavior seems to depend on the GCC version.

If you call `f` with a null pointer constant as argument, then the call is ambiguous, because the null pointer constant can be converted to a null pointer value of any pointer type and this conversion has same rank as the conversion of `int` (or any integral type) to `double`.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler works correctly, in accordance to [[over.match]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/#over) and  [[conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/#conv), more specifically [conv.fpint] and [conv.ptr].

> A standard conversion sequence is [blah blah] Zero or one [...] floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, [...].

and

> A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of a floating-point type. The result is exact if possible [blah blah]

and

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal with value zero or [...]. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type [blah blah]

Now, overload resolution is to choose the best match among **all** candidate functions (which, as a fun feature, need not even be accessible at the call location!). The best match is the one with exact parameters or, alternatively, the fewest possible conversions. Zero or one standard conversions may happen (... for every parameter), and zero is "better" than one.

`(1-1)` is an integer literal with value `0`.

You can convert the zero integer literal to **each** of either `double` or `double*` (or `nullptr_t`), with **exactly one** conversion. So, assuming that more than one of these functions is declared (as is the case in the example), there exists more than a single candidate, and all candidates are equally good, there exists no best match. It's ambiguous, and the compiler is right about complaining.

Comment: How is `1-1` an [integer literal](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex#nt:integer-literal)? It is an expression containing two integer literals with value `1` and a `-` operator.

Comment: @walnut: You probably refer to the awkward wording _"sequence of binary-digits, octal-digits, digits, or hexadecimal-digits"_. That's a very unluckily wording for something rather "obvious", which suggests something that isn't the case (i.e. excluding the minus character). With just "digits", and pedantically per the definition of "digit" (one of 0...9), it is not possible to have _any_ negative literals (such as `-1`). Which, since the default type is _signed_, however, is obviously necessary, and it's demonstrably possible (and universally accepted), too.

Comment: I am referring to the grammar for *integer-literal* shown in the standard link, which doesn't match `1-1`. C++ doesn't have negative integer literals. `-1` is an expression made up of a `1` integer literal (of signed type) and a `-` unary minus operator. See also the "Notes" section [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: It is certainly true that the grammar does not have it, but that's widely inconsequential. By necessity and by definition, C++ very much _does have_ negative literals, since unless you explicitly append `u`, your literal is, per definition, signed. Signed types _do have_ negative values (about 50% of the possible values are negative). It is unfortunate that the grammar (for a reason that I wouldn't know) is misleading in this way, and although technically (according to grammar) -1 is a positive literal, negated, by all other means is is of course a negative literal. Much like 3+4 is a literal.

Comment: By the way -- I tried `0U`.  Same issue.  What I did not try is an `enum` value.  Maybe a named one would've changed things.  I ended up writing a long expression with `decltype` and `remove_reference`.